# Output in lists turns everything into individual strings

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to insert something into a new list and get an output that says:
    vehicle is 7 letters

```
fl=['vehicle','person']
Textfl=[]     
Textfl.extend(str(fl[0])+ "is " +str(len(fl[0]))+ "letters")
print(Textfl)
```

Ends up returning:

```
['v', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'c', 'l', 'e', 'i', 's' ' ', '7', 'l', 'e', 't', 't', 'e', 'r', 's']
```

Wanted output: `vehicle is 7 letters`

Comment: You probably meant [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=append). `extend()` is for combining sequences, and `str` is considered a sequence.

Comment: Do you want it for all the elements in the list?

Comment: Cool, what are the general differences between the two functions? Because extend works when added whole blocks of strings into an existing list with strings already in it.

Comment: Do you really want the result in a `list`? Or just need a string output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) for a cleaner solution:

For Python [3.6+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

```
s = 'vehicle'
output = f'{s} is {len(s)} letters'
# 'vehicle is 7 letters'
```

For older versions use:

```
output = '{} is {} letters'.format(s,len(s))
# 'vehicle is 7 letters'
```

---

The problem with your solution is that you are making the result a list, when you're expected output is actually a string. The following would be enough:

```
str(fl[0]) + " is " + str(len(fl[0]))+ " letters"
# 'vehicle is 7 letters'
```

Comment: You probably should make a comment that `f-strings` are only available from Py3.6+, this would be confusing to a beginner if they are not running Py3.6+. And maybe show the alternative is `.format()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fl = ['vehicle', 'person']
Textfl = str()
Textfl = fl[0]+ " is " + str(len(fl[0])) + " letters"
print(Textfl)
```

Try to use the Textfl object as string.

Comment: `Textfl = str()` is not necessary.

Comment: yeah, i know but it's cleaner with separate declaration and it is a good programming behavior. especially here where that was the part of the problem.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed so `Textfl = str()` is meaningless and is not considered good programming behaviour in python. Python does have type hints if you wish to use them: `Textfl: str = ...`

Comment: i know about it... but if you will not only use python, it will be a good practice beside the declaration of a variable(despite the dynamically typing) always will produce a much more readable and cleaner result. every code is read much more often than it is written.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `list` in output containing an element `vehicle is 7 letters` then you can do something like this:

```
fl=['vehicle','person']
Textfl=[]     
Textfl.append(str(fl[0])+" "+"is " +str(len(fl[0]))+" "+"letters")
print(Textfl)
```

output

```
['vehicle is 7 letters']
```